# How to allow menu item to overflow the app height in a .NET MAUI Windows app using XAML?

Tags: .net, maui

Currently, the menu items are restricted to the height of the app, this makes it look congested.

The expected behavior is for example, as in the screenshot, the menuitem's flyoutitems are expected to overflow beyond the app's height.

[Screenshot of expected behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBjfl.png)

At present, the code for the menu is something like the follows.

```
<ContentPage ...>
<ContentPage.MenuBarItems> 
    <MenuBarItem Text="Locations">            
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Add Location"
                        Command="{Binding AddLocationCommand}" />
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Edit Location"
                        Command="{Binding EditLocationCommand}" />
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Remove Location"
                        Command="{Binding RemoveLocationCommand}" />                            
    </MenuBarItem>
</ContentPage.MenuBarItems>
```

I tried to do some modifications on the menubar item tag, however, they made no difference.

Comment: Do you mean you want to make the `MenuBarItem` drop downs shown outside of the app's shown area?

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT, yes that’s correct.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I don't think you can overflow the menu items as you said, you may raise a [feature request](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/new?assignees=&labels=proposal%2Fopen%2Ct%2Fenhancement&projects=&template=feature-request.yml) on Github.